# Unterstanding eventlet.wsgi.server

Tags: python, http, asynchronous, wsgi, eventlet

I have this simple Python programm:

```
from eventlet import wsgi
import eventlet
from eventlet.green import time

def hello_world(env, start_response):
    print "got request"
    time.sleep(10)
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
    return ['Hello, World!\n']

wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 8090)), hello_world)
```

So when i run it, and open `http://localhost:8090/` on my browser multiple times, `got request` is only printed after the first request was already processed (after 10 seconds).
It seems like `eventlet.wsgi.server` is processing the requests synchronously. But I am using the "green" `sleep`. sow how can this happen?

Thank you!

Comment: i took a look at `wsgi.py` every request is processed on a seperate (green) thread `pool.spawn_n(serv.process_request, client_socket)` and the pool maxium size is 1024...

Comment: are you sure you have unbuffered output ?

Comment: do yo know how i can check this?

Comment: You can run python in unbuffered mode (python -u) and there's also the PYTHONUNBUFFERED=x enviroment var you could set.

Comment: its funny, but my main application is working well, but this simple test not, anyway... thank you for the help!

Comment: I can confirm the problem exist, don't know the answer, yet I observed more clue.
The problem seems relative to the client IP! Because if you open your browser to visit `http://localhost:8090` and `http://192.168.1.2:8090`, both quickly trigger the **got request** message. However if you fire up more requests, they wait until the first two finish.
Note: Here I assume your machine's ip is 192.168.1.2

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the monkey patch as below:

```
eventlet.patcher.monkey_patch(all=False, socket=True, time=True,
                          select=True, thread=True, os=True)
```

More information could be found from this [link](http://eventlet.net/doc/patching.html#monkeypatching-the-standard-library).